# Laravel Event Listeners and Manual Release

Tags: laravel

I'm using laravel docs using Event Listener with Manually Accessing The Queue.

here is my code:

```
$user = $event->user;

    if ($user->first_name == 'User1') {
        $this->release(30);
    }

    $this->mailer->send('emails.user.welcome', ['user' => $user], function ($m) use ($user) {
        $m->subject('Thank you for registering at ' . env('APP_NAME'))->to($user->email);
    });
```

The problem is the email is send before 30 secs and after 30 secs it send again. I've got problem understanding it.

Isn't it suppose to release at 30 secs (only once)?

Update:
What I want try to achieve is, send the welcome mail after 30secs if the user name is user1.

Thanks.

Updated Code:

```
 if ($user->first_name == 'Stefen'  && $this->attempts() === 0){
        var_dump('this will send later');
        $this->release(10);
    } else{
        $this->mailer->send('emails.user.welcome', ['user' => $user], function ($m) use ($user) {
            $m->subject('Thank you for registering at ' . env('APP_NAME'))->to($user->email);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Why are you wanting to send an email _specifically_ 30 seconds later?

Comment: yes. But using `$this-release` instead of `Mail::later` @MartinBean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `release` method doesn't terminate the function, it simply pushes the job back *n* seconds into the queue, then continues with the rest of that handler. Try this instead:

```
    if ($user->first_name == 'User1' && $this->attempts() === 1)
    {
        $this->release(30);
    }
    else
    {
        // Mail time.
    }
```

More on queues:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues

Comment: Hi, i saw at my terminal it process the queue. But it not releasing the email.

Comment: Echo the value of `attempts`. From how I read the documentation, that should start at 0 and increase 1 per attempt.

Comment: `attempts` is 1. function enter to else instead of if statement

Comment: And.. just to make sure ... you've put the functional email code instead of the comment, right? If so, and the logic is executing as you'd expect (if bracket 1 first try, else other try), your problem is now something different than what you're asking about.

Comment: I've updated my question. What I want try to achieve is, send the welcome mail after 30secs if the user name is user1. Using `$this-release` instead of `Mail::later`

Comment: What I have given you should accomplish that as long as the mail code works.

Comment: The mail is working. But it send directly instead of waiting for 10 sec. Will post my code

Comment: When you are echoing `->attempts()`, are you seeing 0 then 1? If not, change the first clause to be `=== 1` instead.

Comment: I just saw 1. no 0

Comment: Okay, so attempts must be 1-indexed instead of 0-indexed. Try making that change.

Comment: NOw it working. THanks. Would mind explain a lil bit. How come laravel can know the job? It's in the else statement. And it wont get there right?

Comment: Laravel uses a CRON entry to cycle through its job queue every minute. When you release the job, you are telling Laravel to try again in 30 seconds. The next time the cycle happens, if 30 seconds have passed, it tries again -- this time with `attempts()` equalling 2 instead of 1. Laravel does not send the mail unless your criteria is met, which it does not the first time it tries to send the job because it equals 1 then. The next time it attempts it, which is after the release, it will not be 1 and the else condition occurs.

Comment: Thanks!!. Now it all make sense. I wish I could vote more than one!